# Set values in environment for spring boot application in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: java, spring-mvc, environment-variables, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to set below values in enviornment (Ubuntu 22.04)

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
```

I have set values in enviornment as

```
export spring_datasource_url_prefix=mysql 
export spring_datasource_host=localhost 
export spring_datasource_port=3306 
export spring_datasource_database=abc 
export spring_datasource_username=root 
export spring_datasource_password=root
```

And in my Spring Boot `application.properties` file I have used it as

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:${spring_datasource_url_prefix}://${spring_datasource_host}:${spring_datasource_port}/${spring_datasource_database}
spring.datasource.username=${spring_datasource_username}
spring.datasource.password=${spring_datasource_password}
```

But I am unable to fetch values using this. Am I missing anything or doing it wrong? I have tried setting enviornment through nano `.bashrc` and as mentioned above.

I am getting error as

```
Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
```

I have also tried it as below

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:${spring_datasource_url_prefix}://${spring_datasource_host}:${spring_datasource_port}/${spring_datasource_database}
spring.datasource.username=${spring_datasource_username}
spring.datasource.password=${spring_datasource_password}
```

I am getting error as below

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
[2m2023-05-15 17:30:06.909[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2208925[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-05-15 17:30:06.929[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2208925[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2023-05-15 17:30:06.931[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m2208925[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't. You are really overcomplicating things. Leave the application context as is, don't change. Name the environment variables `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` (all uppercase) and Spring Boot will automatically use those instead of the values from the `application.properties`.

```bash
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc?useSSL=false 
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root 
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
```

Spring Boot will automatically use these, instead of the ones from `application.properties`.

Comment: I used this but it still gives same error saying , 

Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
```

Comment: Do you have the mysql driver on the classpath, it doesn't appear so. You need to add it as a dependency. My code also contained a typo, I modified it (which is also what the error tells you and that is what you get when you are blindly copy/pasting code from StackOverflow :) ). .

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>8.0.28</version>
  </dependency>

I have added this dependency

Comment: Have you tried again with the proper URL?

Comment: Yes  "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useSSL=false"

Comment: And the error you get is? If it doesn't find the class, you haven't (properly) included the dependency.

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'

Comment: Why did you use `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useSSL=false"`? The value must not be quoted.

Comment: I have set that in environment

Comment: export SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useSSL=false

export SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root 
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
```


spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}

Comment: Sigh... As I stated in the answer and my comment do not include those in your `application.properties`. Spring Boot will **automatically use them**.

Comment: okk... I tried that removing that from application.properties and now I am getting error  as

"Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Comment: Tried running application using mvn -q spring-boot:run in terminal, it works. 
But not through eclipse IDE.

Comment: If you do `export` in a shell it will only apply to that shell instance. You will need to make it available globally.

Comment: "By adding the export statements to the .bashrc file in your home directory, you are configuring the system to set those environment variables every time a new shell session is started. This makes the variables available globally within the user's environment."

I have followed this and saved values in .bashrc file. But not working. 
My aim is to get env values from .properties file

Comment: Read... Again read... **SHELL ENVIRONMENT**... Eclipse is **NOT** a Shell Environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below website's detailed explanation:
[Baledung - env variables](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-properties-env-variables)
[JavaRevisited -  env variables](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2022/04/how-to-use-environment-variables-in.html#axzz81mTBzn6P)

Other things to consider are:

1. After executing your .bashrc, did you verify the exported variables are registered successfully and available to the application.
2. Which profile like dev,uat or these directly set in the "application.properties"?

Comment: yes I verified it is registered in enviornment. I am directly setting in the "application.properties" file

Comment: Tried running application using mvn -q spring-boot:run in terminal, it works. But not through eclipse IDE.

Comment: @GShares `mvn -q --  "-q,--quiet  Quiet output - only show errors"` with the `mvn -q  spring-boot:run` you are essentially booting the application with mvn which is better explained in below example and while running with eclipse IDE you need to look at the run configuration. Why you are referring the properties from environment variables and the properties file, you can do with either of them. 
[Execute spring boot mvn vs jar](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-run-maven-vs-executable-jar) \ [Data source error solution](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failed-to-configure-data-source)